# JAVA - set font of selectedtext in a JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, document, rtf

How can I set the font/bold/italic/underline whatever of some text in a JEditorPane?

I am trying to create a simple document editor, but i can only figure out how to set the font/bold/italic/whatever of the ENTIRE JEditor/JText pane.

RTF is preferred, HTML is fine as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JEditorPane.getDocument() returns an instance of StyledDocument. StyledDocument has [setCharacterAttributes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledDocument.html#setCharacterAttributes%28int,%20int,%20javax.swing.text.AttributeSet,%20boolean%29)() method to set the font properties.

Related example: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JTextPanesetCharacterAttributesAttributeSetattrbooleanreplace.htm