# Java - Set Font size of selection in a JEditorPane?

Tags: java, swing, document, font-size, jeditorpane

[Thanks to devsundar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11231204/714968) I found out how to make the selected text in a `JEditorPane` bold/underline/italics/whatever. How can I set the `Font Size` of the selected Text in a `JEditorPane`?

My Current Method Of changing bold/italics/etc:

```
 AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY,
    StyleConstants.StrikeThrough, true);

 pane.getStyledDocument().setCharacterAttributes(pane.getSelectionStart(),
    pane.getSelectionEnd(), aset, true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a working example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8534162/230513) that uses `StyledEditorKit.FontSizeAction` and related classes in [`StyledEditorKit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledEditorKit.html).

[image]

Comment: I do need to add buttons to my GUI, so this will work! Thanks!

Comment: Excellent; see also `HTMLDocumentEditor`, mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10160836/230513).